# how to keep space between two digit in input tag

Tags: javascript, html

In input tag after time there should alway be one space, user should not be allowed to remove that space after time, want some method in JavaScript

07:00 AM

Comment: Post your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fname");
    if(x.value.length!=0)
    {    
    x.value=x.value+" ";
    }
  }
```

```html
<html>
<body>

Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onkeypress="myFunction()">

<p>When you press key into the input field, a function is triggered add space after one char .</p>
<p>If you give space in text box,its two time display, but you can overcome it</p>

</body>
</html>
```